# How to cast callback 'Function' type?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using 'http' node module in typescript.

I know, if `response.setEncoding` then call `response.on`, I got callback with 'string'. so I try to cast 'string'. But I got error `TS2352: Neither type 'Function' nor type 'string' is assignable to the other.`

like this

```
import * as http from "http";
import {IncomingMessage} from "http";

http.get("http://example.com", (response: IncomingMessage) => {
    response.setEncoding("utf8");
    response.on("data", (listener: Function) => {
        if (typeof listener === "string") {
            let matchArray: RegExpMatchArray = (listener as string).match(/a/g); // TS2352: Neither type 'Function' nor type 'string' is assignable to the other.
            console.log(matchArray);
        }
    });
});
```

How to cast `listener` to `string` or proper way to get `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter `listener` can be a `Function` or a `string`, then it could be declared with an union type `Function|string`:

```
import * as http from "http";
import {IncomingMessage} from "http";

http.get("http://example.com", (response: IncomingMessage) => {
    response.setEncoding("utf8");
    response.on("data", (listener: Function|string) => {
        if (typeof listener === "string") {
            let matchArray: RegExpMatchArray = listener.match(/a/g);
            console.log(matchArray);
        }
    });
});
```